# PHP timetable statement

Tags: php

I am currently working to improve a PHP timetable. A statement being used by the timetable is:

```
echo $array2['username'] ? $array2['username'] : '-';
```

I understand that echo is displaying the information but why is there is a question mark? also what is the purpose of the colon?

I'm trying to advancde the above line to include PHP if statements and also a href tag so I need to know what the above statement is doing in order to break it up so I can recode appropriately.

Comment: Look for PHP ternary statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: its a ternary statement read this http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are `ternary operators`. it is equivalent to an `if-else` statement.

The statement above is trying to see if the index `username` is present or set. if `true`, it uses the value of index `username`. else, it returns an empty string.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: